# How to display the array which is in objective C to the HTML or JavaScript,to display the contents of array on a buttonclick in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, arrays

How to display the array which is in objective C to the HTML or JavaScript,to display the contents of array on a buttonclick in HTML,

The following code is my .m File code,

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Array"ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];

       NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Example" ofType:@"csv"];
       NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
       NSArray *lines = [contents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n,"]];
       for (NSString* line in lines) {

                NSLog(@"%@", line);


                }
               NSLog(@" %d", [lines count]);

    [self.webView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"checkContents = new Array%@",lines] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

The following is my HTML file Code,

```
function checkContents(Lines) {
                  // alert("test...");
                  alert(checkContents[0]);
                    // alert(document.lines[0]);

                    if (typeof(checkContents)=='undefined') 
                    ....
                    else {
                        if (checkContents.length == 0) 
                        ....
                        else { 
                            for (i=0; i<checkContents.length; i++) {


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

<body onload="checkContents()">
<div class="greybutton" onClick="javascript:checkContents()">contents</a></div>
</body>
```

When i run this program it displays Undefined as the output in the alert, am I missing any code in the HTML file or where i am doing the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CFArrayRef

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFArrayRef/Reference/reference.html

which is a C class where NSArray is obj-c version of it. You can change types on the fly, so you can change to it and use C-types string sent to javascript.